# Apache + mod_ssl configuration settings not being used

Tags: mod-ssl

The configuration settings i set in httpd.conf don't seem to be actually working. After restarting Apache I used some online SSL check type websites and it appears that Apache isn't using the SSLProtocol configurations.

Tests show that SSL v3 is still enabled even though it is set not to in my apache config file.

I've had to install a separate certificate in a different VZ container and followed the same process and everything appears to be working fine.

Here is what I have in my httpd.conf

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 
SSLHonorCipherOrder On 
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
    ServerName domain.org
    ServerAlias www.domain.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/domain.org.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/domain_org.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Are there any settings that could be overriding the SSLProtocol configuration ? I just need a point in the right direction to try and figure out what it going on here as it is my understanding that i have everything setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

inside the VirtualHost container like:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
    ServerName domain.org
    ServerAlias www.domain.org
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/domain.org.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/domain_org.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

you have probably still some Virtual Hosts running SSLv3 so the whole servers responds to SSLv3.

See [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162478/how-to-disable-sslv3-in-apache)